# I get a "document.getElementById(...) is null" message error and have no idea why

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely new to coding and I know similar questions have been asked in the past, yet I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm working on a very basic website, using almost exclusively HTML + CSS, and a tiny bit of JavaScript.

I want to trigger a basic popup message while clicking on a "Submit" button inside a form.

However I keep getting the following message: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` and I can't figure out why.

This is my code:

```js
const message = "Thank you for submitting your message.";

document.getElementById("contact-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(message);
});
```

```html
<!-- Contact Form -->
<main>
  <h1>Contact the Royal Kingdom</h1>
  <form id="contact-form">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name..." />
    <br />
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="default@example.com" required />
    <br />
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <br />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</main>

<!-- Connect the Javascript file -->
```

I `console.logged` typeof `document.getElementById("contact-form")` and it returned `null`.

If it's of any interest, I'm using CodeSandBox.io.

I'm totally stuck, which is even more frustrating considering how easy the solution probably is... Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Runs fine when I test it on jsfiddle and codesandbox. Have you tested the code somewhere other than codesandbox?

Comment: I moved your html and js code into a snippet that we can run right from here. Seems to be working okay. Can you modify it to reproduce your issue?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I tested it on jsfiddle and works like a charm! I reloaded codesandbox and it worked... until I typed something (I typed "const" right after) in the js file and the error appeared again, which doesn't make much sense to me :( I read somewhere it might be due to the order in which the page loads

Comment: here's a link to the full project https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-code-school-tech-challenge-forked-intv0

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if the JavaScript is running before the HTML exists

Comment: Yep. I looked at your codepen. Move the script before the closing body tag, use the defer attribute, or use an event listener to delay the JS until the HTML is ready.

Comment: so I used <script src="script.js" defer></script>, the script was already before the closing body tag so left it where it was. But the problem is still there unfortunately

Comment: Outside of CodeSandBox.io, this usually occurs when the javascript file loads before the HTML and therefore the id doesn't exist at the time the javascript file has loaded.  This is usually solved two ways, one: put the script tag with the external javascript at the bottom of the body; two: if it is in the head, add the attribute "defer". I don't think this will solve your problem in "CodeSandBox.io" (which I'm not particularly familiar with) but it will help if you have the problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually put the JS directly in the HTML file, instead of in a dedicated script.js file as I did initially. And it now runs flawlessly, though I still don't get why really...

```
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Contact the Royal Kingdom</h1>
    <form id="contact-form">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name..." />
        <br />
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="default@example.com" required />
        <br />
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <br />
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message..."></textarea>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</main>
<script>
    const message = "Thank you for submitting your message.";
    document.getElementById("contact-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(message);
    });
</script>
```

Thank you to everyone for your help!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.